# How to enable systemd's journal audit transport?

Tags: linux, logging, opensuse, systemd, auditd

I have been studying logging on Linux but I have come to a road-block that's got me stuck for the past few days. My goal is to forward logs from two raspberry pi 3's running OpenSUSE Tumbleweed (aarch64) to my laptop running Ubuntu 17.04. I'm using `rsyslog` to accomplish this which is using `imjournal` as the source because I want to store the logs in json format with all the extra metadata provided by the systemd-journal and play with that later.

The problem I am trying to address is a lack of `_TRANSPORT=audit` on my raspberry pi's. I recompiled `systemd` with `audit` support on one of my pi's thinking that would solve the problem, but it hasn't. I have also added `audit=1` to the kernel command line on the pi's and rebooted them. My laptop supports the `audit` transport.

Here's the output of `journalctl --version`, `sudo journalctl --field _TRANSPORT`, and `cat /proc/cmdline`  on my various systems.

laptop:

```
$ journalctl --version
systemd 232
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP 
+LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS 
+KMOD +IDN

$ sudo journalctl --field _TRANSPORT
syslog
stdout
journal
audit
driver
kernel

$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-33-generic.efi.signed 
root=UUID=cf4dc10b-511a-4369-ad5c-637833244929 ro apparmor=1 
security=apparmor
```

rpi1 (reconfigured `systemd` with `audit` support):

```
$ journalctl --version
systemd 234
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX -IMA +APPARMOR -SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP 
+LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS 
+KMOD -IDN2 -IDN default-hierarchy=hybrid

$ sudo journalctl --field _TRANSPORT
stdout
kernel
journal
syslog
driver

$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/Image-4.4.83-5-default root=UUID=30bbe534-b90f-4de6-
a0e6-1e2b60088461 root=/dev/disk/by-id/mmc-ACLCD_0xd02f42e5-part2 
disk=/dev/disk/by-id/mmc-ACLCD_0xd02f42e5 resume=/dev/disk/by-id/mmc-
ACLCD_0xd02f42e5-part3 quiet splash=silent plymouth.enable=0 
swiotlb=512,force cma=384M console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty quiet 
audit=1
```

rpi2 (with original `systemd` configured by the distro):

```
$ journalctl --version
systemd 234
+PAM -AUDIT +SELINUX -IMA +APPARMOR -SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP 
+LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL+XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS 
+KMOD -IDN2 -IDN default-hierarchy=hybrid

$ sudo journalctl --field _TRANSPORT
stdout
kernel
journal
syslog
driver

cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/Image-4.4.83-5-default root=UUID=30bbe534-b90f-4de6-
a0e6-1e2b60088461 root=/dev/disk/by-id/mmc-ACLCD_0xcaf643ee-part2 
disk=/dev/disk/by-id/mmc-ACLCD_0xcaf643ee resume=/dev/disk/by-id/mmc-
ACLCD_0xcaf643ee-part3 quiet splash=silent plymouth.enable=0 
swiotlb=512,force cma=384M console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=tty quiet 
audit=1
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to get the audit transport available for `systemd-journald` on my rpi's. I have the `auditd.service` and `systemd-journald-audit.socket` enabled and active on all my systems. If you need any other infos just let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would check these things:

- The  `systemd-journald-audit.socket` is configured to listen to a socket using the `AF_NETLINK` protocol. If `systemctl status systemd-journald-audit.socket` is not active, then `systemd-journald.service` is not using it.
- Ensure `systemd-journald-audit.socket` is included in`Sockets=systemd-journald.socket systemd-journald-dev-log.socket systemd-journald-audit.socket` in the `systemd-journald.service` definition.

  If missing from your default `systemd-journald.service`, create an override at `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service.d/override.conf`:

  ```
  # systemctl edit systemd-journald.service
  [Service]
  Sockets=
  Sockets=systemd-journald.socket systemd-journald-dev-log.socket systemd-journald-audit.socket
  # systemctl restart systemd-journald.service
  ```
- `audit=0` has not been set as a kernel parameter. Check with `cat /proc/cmdline`.

Verify that audit is now in your set of field type `_TRANSPORT`

```
# journalctl --field _TRANSPORT
stdout
kernel
syslog
journal
audit
driver
```